# In Keras, how can I load images to GPU in groups larger than batch size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have the following code segment:

```
model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=2, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), initial_epoch=0)    
print(model.evaluate(test_x, test_y))
```

My GPU will still work with a batch size of 1024. However, this will severely penalize the frequency with which the model updates. Is it possible to load the images in groups of 1024 to the GPU but adjust the weights for the model every 32 images?

My intention is to improve performance by reducing the number of times the GPU has to fetch data from main memory since there is high latency involved with this operation. My question is similar to this one: [How can you load all batch data into GPU memory in Keras (Theano backend)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944174/how-can-you-load-all-batch-data-into-gpu-memory-in-keras-theano-backend)
However, I am not necessarily trying to load all my data to the GPU at once, as the dataset is too large.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not what you're asking but... how do you know there's "high latency"? What's your setup? Even if what you're asking were possible, I'd expect negligible performance improvement in a standard setting. Memory bandwidth for GTX1080 is 320 GB/s, while latency of the main memory is ~200 ns.